# Trouble fetching a phone number using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to fetch a phone number connected to a javascript link visible as `Phone Us` from a webpage. I know I can use selenium to click on that link and wait until the number is visible in order to parse that but I'm not interested to go that route.

[Main link](https://www.cv-library.co.uk/list-jobs/276692/Allen-York-Built-and-Natural-Environment-Ltd)

[image]

However, when I manually click on that link after opening chrome dev tools to see the network activity in xhr tab, I could find out this link `https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=192205` along with the following headers which produces some json reponse containing the phone number I'm after.

Headers taken from chrome dev tools:

```
:authority: www.cv-library.co.uk
:method: GET
:path: /account-contact-details?id=192205
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
cookie: job_search_bar_variant=variant_C_labels_above; _ga=GA1.3.807796815.1553681717; _gid=GA1.3.728310157.1553681717; _gcl_au=1.1.1379982900.1553681717; _fbp=fb.2.1553681722126.942064476; tempbasket=1553681845451186016; ui_hidecookienotice=1; session=1553697454.46289%3ABQkDAAAAAA%3D%3D%3A375400f1f62664342b2c0bd1e6bcd9c89170768b; _gat_UA-23741307-1=1
referer: https://www.cv-library.co.uk/list-jobs/276692/Allen-York-Built-and-Natural-Environment-Ltd
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

General section looks like this:

```
Request URL: https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=192205
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 109.169.5.15:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response it produces in the browser:

```
{email: "", telephone: "01202 888986"}
```

I've tried this:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=192205"

headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.cv-library.co.uk/list-jobs/276692/Allen-York-Built-and-Natural-Environment-Ltd',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(res)
```

The error it throws:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)
```

***How can I fetch that phone number using requests?***

Comment: do res.content instead of json, it might not be what you expect it to be

Comment: Then what it would be @E.Serra? I could not find any phone number within res.content.

Comment: it is definitely not a json which is what you are telling it to expect

Comment: I don't even get a valid response. I'm getting `404`

Comment: Consider that approach to be a placeholder @E.Serra. Thanks.

Comment: you are getting 404 whihc is not found, which probably means you are not allowed to see that https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details?id=192205, you need some authorization or sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'` in your headers:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/account-contact-details"

headers = {
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {'id':'192205'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get(url,headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
print (res['telephone'])
01202 888986
```

Comment: Grrr! only the header that I didn't try with. I wish I could upvote your solution million times @chitown88!!!